# What happened to my code? --too many arguments Python error--

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

So I have following code which eventually worked until some time ago:

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from SerialMonitor import Ui_SerialMonitor

    class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
            self.ui = Ui_SerialMonitor()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.readButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.startReading)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.stopButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.stopReading)

        def startReading(self):
            print("1")
            self.ui.stopButton.isEnabled(False)

        def stopReading(self):
           print("2")
           self.ui.readButton.isEnabled(True)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        myapp = StartQT4()
        myapp.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After a couple of tries this code somewhat died and now it returns:

> line 13, in **init**
>      self.ui.button_save.isEnabled(True)
>   TypeError: QWidget.isEnabled(): too many arguments

Can't actually figure out what happened. The funny thing is that other similar codes, which worked normally before, now stopped working with the same error.

Comment: Try `setEnabled(True)` instead of `isEnabled(True)`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm! Do you have any idea what happened? Ninja Edit: looks more like my bad and a typo..

Comment: Maybe this code has never been called before?

Comment: BTW, I made my comment an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setEnabled(True)` instead of `isEnabled(True)`.